# Non linear recurrence from a different problem here

Tags: recurrence-relations

Referring to [Non linear recurrence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630650/non-linear-recurrence-relation/1632944#1632944)
"The recurrence (2) then implies that
$ h_m=h_0+md$ for (m≥0)", What does $h_0$ refer to and how is it derived?

From what I can see in equation(2), when $g_m=1$,$h_m = 2h_{m+1} + h_{m+2}$ so how does $h_0+md$ come about?

Comment: $h_m-h_{m+1}$ is shown to be constant, so $h_m= m(h_1-h_0)+h_0$

Comment: I believe the question asks for explicit functions of f, any ideas of how to get them?